Как скопировать текст в ячейку
Подскажите, как скопировать в exel рядок, чтобы в том рядке, где вставляю сохранилась информация. Может есть способ быстрее кроме копирования ячеек?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Смотрите, у меня в первом рядке информация в ячеейке В и С, во втором рядке информация в рядке А и D. как обьеденить информацю всю в первый ряд?

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Благодарю за помощь!

@ЕкатеринаМордюшенко Если мой ответ Вам помог - отметьте его галочкой

Для объединения есть функция СЦЕПИТЬ или оператор &

=СЦЕПИТЬ(B1; C1; " "; A2; " "; D2) - здесь " " добавляет пробел между значениями, можете изменить на любой другой разделитель;
=B1 & " " & C1 & " " & A2 & " " & D2 - здесь после выполнения в ячейке A1 будет объединенная информация из ячеек.

